# Вопрос из Русского медвежонка

Tags: существительные, род

Внук-пятиклассник пришел ко мне проконсультироваться по одному из вопросов "Русского медвежонка", но я не смог ему помочь.

Вопрос звучит так: "По какому из этих географических названий можно без словаря однозначно определить, к какому роду оно относится?"

Варианты ответов:

А) Свислочь.
Б) Сычуань.
В) Улюколь.
Г) Ловать. 
Д) Пльзень.

Обычно род географического названия определяется по родовому понятию, но они здесь не указаны, а есть лишь названия. Крутил я эти слова во все стороны, но никакой мысли не возникло. Может, постарел? Возможно, среди форумчан найдется светлая голова, которая ответит на этот вопрос.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это же с русским языком связано, значит, выбираем Свислочь, потому что это точно 3 склонение, жен. род на мягкий шипящий: рожь, дочь. Остальные могут относиться ко 2 склонению.

Answer (score -1):

Тут географию знать надо. Есть город Свислочь, а есть  и река. Есть поселок  Оять, и река с тем же именем. Озеро Улюколь, деревня с тем же именем. Китайская провинция Сычуань, город Пльзень, Река Ловать.
Если знаешь географию -- и то проблемы. Есть село Ловать, с речкой никак не связано.

В общем, не зная наверняка, определить чисто по названию род топонима или гидронима --равносильно угадайке, особенно с импортом. В той же Чехии есть  Ку́тна-Го́ра, вот и пойми, женского или мужского рода...

Comment: В том-то и дело, что это младшие классы, вопрос на сообразительность и только на знание русского языка, география ни при чём:"По какому из этих географических названий можно без словаря однозначно определить, к какому роду оно относится?" Не зная, река это или город,однозначно Свислочь - жен., иначе бы писалось без мягкого знака.Кстати, не знала, что есть город с таким названием.

Comment: Город Свислочь — все равно женского рода. Может быть название города женского рода? Так вот, Свислочь — совершенно точно женского. Почему — Людмила объяснила.

Comment: Ильмень не удовлетворяет правилу с мягким знаком. А уж  если  ребенку сказать слово  Этиленгликоль, и попросить определить род из ваших соображений, он  ведь химии тоже не знает?  Город НИкель из той же серии. Мое мнение: не дури те детям голову раньше времени.